# Trying to find a limit by estimating it with a Riemann sum

Tags: limits

I am trying to find the limit
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^{2}+n+k^{2}}.$$

I first look for an upper bound as a Riemann sum of an integral as follows
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^{2}+n+k^{2}}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n} \frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}}\\
& \leq \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \cdot \frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{1+x^{2}}\,dx.
\end{aligned}
$$

I want to squeeze this series to get the limit , but I failed to find the smaller side.

Comment: your first equality is weird... You still have an $i$ in the expression

Comment: Your finite sum is given by $$\frac{1}{2} \left(-\psi ^{(0)}\left(1-\sqrt{-n
   (n+1)}\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(n-\sqrt{-n
   (n+1)}+1\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\sqrt{-n
   (n+1)}+1\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\sqrt{-n
   (n+1)}+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: $\psi$ denotes the polygamma function.

Comment: @DrSonnhardGraubner Doesn't that term simplify drastically when one pulls out the $\phi$?

Comment: You need to rewrite the $\lim$ and the sum at each step. Otherwise you don't have equations/inequalities at all the steps. I took the liberty to polish the TeX a bit as well. For example, an equation is displayed on a line by itself, centered even, automatically if you surround it by double dollars. See the source code for this and the other features I added. Also, we like to have at least some plain text in the title, and the question body should be self-contained (as opposed to rely on the title).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bothering with both the upper and lower bound, we may investigate how the removing of $n$ from the denominator affects the limit. To this end, we may look at the difference

$$ \left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+n+i^2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2 + i^2} \right| \tag{*}$$

and then it suffices to show this vanishes as $n\to\infty$. But

\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+n+i^2} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2 + i^2} \right|
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left| \frac{i}{n^2+n+i^2} - \frac{i}{n^2 + i^2} \right| \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{ni}{(n^2+n+i^2)(n^2 + i^2)} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n\cdot n}{n^2 \cdot n^2}
 = \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align*}

Now in view of the squeezing lemma, it follows that $\text{(*)}$ converges to $0$ and therefore

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+n+i^2}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+i^2}
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: can I use this method in any question that need squeezing?

Comment: @nevermind_15 Although I cannot tell that this method works for any such questions, it is quite systematic and has great flexibility that often works well for textbook-level questions. So you may consider this an alternative when it is not obvious how to come up with upper/lower bounds as Riemann sums.